# In YAML, how do I make a comment over multiple lines

Tags: comments, yaml

I know that you can make a single line comment in YAML by using the `#` tag, but I haven't been able to find something like `/*` in java that starts a comment & has to be finished off with a `*/`. Does such an operator exist in YAML?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

YAML does not support multiple line comments. If you want to use them. You can just try

```
# this
# is a multiple
# line comment
```